# How can I effectively speed level?

Tags: killing-floor-2

What is the fastest way to level each perk so far?
It just seems so tedious to heal others and deal medic weapon damage for Medic Exp; and it seems like it takes forever to weld doors just to level support.

What ways can I speed level in Killing Floor 2?

Comment: Used to be worse, at least you get XP for medic weapon kills now. :)

Comment: The game only exited Beta yesterday...

Comment: Custom leveling/XP maps, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it boils down to damaging zeds with perk weapons (or any weapon if you are playing as survivalist)

The secondary xp objectives only count for tiny amounts of xp, like killing a crawler as gunslinger yields **10xp** 
(on hard or suicidal, can't remember), with a headshot kill being a measly **11xp**

This being said, doesn't mean you shouldn't weld doors/heal/go for headshots, but don't make it your objective.

***The best way to get XP is to have fun with your friends, preferably in long games. Difficulty I would recommend is hard, suicidal if you're feeling confident*** (the difficulty difference from hard->suicidal->HOE is very high, while the xp gain difference is very little)

Answer (score 3):

You can play as solo 10 waves normal/hard for the beginning you are sure to rack up a nice bodycount and get almost 1 lvl per session you can even solo patriarch with the sledgehammer as berserk or as support with the aa20. With a weapon with a nice spread like the nail gun or the shotguns you can join a high difficulty game and get assists that give lots of xp be carefull not to die tho

Answer (score 1):

The higher the difficulty the more exp. Kills = exp. Not really any farming methods unless you have a good team.